# Extra point getting highlighted when hover

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a line chart using chartJs for this.
as follows 
http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html

When I hover on one point of red line blue line point gets highlighted too.

Is there anything I can solve this.

Comment: We will need to see your code

Comment: Judging by the example, change `hoverMode: 'index'` to the correct value you can find at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html?h=hover